# how to Split a list/array based on index of array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, linq, list, vb.net-2010

I have a list/array of reservation Items

```
Dim reservationItemsarr = ObjTIReadRS.TravelItinerary.ItineraryInfo.ReservationItems.SelectMany(Function(x) x.FlightSegment).ToArray()
```

[image]

now based on some conditions i have made another array which has index of values.

[image]

i need to split the

> reservationItemsarr

i need to create a new list/array that will hold the values based on my index array.

so final result should be be like

> list(0) = reservationItemsarr(0) and reservationItemsarr(1)
>
> list(1) = reservationItemsarr(2) and reservationItemsarr(3) and
>   reservationItemsarr(4)
>
> list(2) = reservationItemsarr(5) and  reservationItemsarr(6) and
>   reservationItemsarr(7)

my problem is not creating a collection of collection, but i need a way to split like above.

Comment: It is not too clear what you have tried to get what you need. I hope that you plainly expecting someone to deliver a full-working solution for you, because this is not how SO works.

Comment: actually i am not looking for a solution, i am looking for some thing like @PHeiberg explained , take and skip would do ... let me try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic algorithm to get you started:

```
Dim results As New List(Of IEnumerable(Of ReservationItem))()
Dim remainder As IEnumerable(Of ReservationItem) = reservationItemsArr
Dim lastIndex As Integer = 0
For i As Integer = 0 To index.Length - 1
    results.Add(remainder.Take(index(i) - lastIndex))
    remainder = remainder.Skip(index(i) - lastIndex)
    lastIndex = index(i)
Next
results.Add(remainder)
```

You need to take care of edge cases such as index pointing at the last element or outside the array.

Comment: thanks for the help, i could solve this.